# Back Camera in portrait using getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, getusermedia

I'm trying to start the back camera in portrait using   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia in react the camera does not seem to take into consideration the constraint that I send this is  how the code looks for the initialization

```
 const constraints = {
                    video: {
                        aspectRatio: 6/19,
                        width: 1920,
                        height: 1080,
                        facingMode: "environment",
                    },
                    audio: false,
                };

     navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
            .then((mediaStream) => {
                video = document.querySelector('video');
                video.srcObject = mediaStream;
                video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
                    video.play();
                };
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(`${err.name}: ${err.message}`);
            });

    <video autoPlay={true} playsInline={true} muted={true} id="video" width="100%" height="100%"></video>
```

I want the back camera to open in full screen while in portrait on a mobile , it seems to be fine while in landscape  it's in full screen, but on portrait it look like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puXhQ.png)

Comment: What kind of device? iOS and Android work differently from each other.

Answer (score 0):

I get you an HTML page for your reference:

```js
async function initCam() {
  try {
    let constraints = {
      "video": {
        facingMode: "environment"            
      }
    };
    let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
    let video = document.getElementById("qq");
    video.srcObject = stream;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  };
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1 1;
}

video {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body onload="initCam()">
  <div class="container">
    <video autoplay muted controls id="qq" />
  </div>
</body>
```

PS: Please run it on a mobile phone, my PC chrome does not "facingMode" constraint.